# ASP.NET MVC3 Create a Form Element using HTML.BeginForm with specific attributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to create a form in my view that will route to a specific controller and action, that will do so as a Get request, and that will have a class attribute "pull-right"

This is what I've tried so far...

```
 using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", "Get", null, new {@class = "pull-right"}))
 {
     <div class="clearfix">
         <label> In as: <strong>@User.Identity.Name</strong></label>
     </div>
     <button class="btn" type="submit">Log Out</button>
 }
```

But it it is throwing an error and I can't figure out how to correctly create this method.  Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: is it throwing error when you click the button or on load of the page? What is the error?

Comment: "it is throwing an error" is useless if you don't tell what the error is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Description

The right overload of the `BeginForm` method should, in your case, this

```
  BeginForm(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string actionName, string controllerName, 
            FormMethod method, object htmlAttributes);
```

**Pass in the `Get` using the enum `FormMethod.Get`**

#### Sample

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Get, new {@class = "pull-right"}))
 {
     <div class="clearfix">
         <label> In as: <strong>@User.Identity.Name</strong></label>
     </div>
     <button class="btn" type="submit">Log Out</button>
 }
```

#### More Information

- [MSDN - FormExtensions.BeginForm-Methode (HtmlHelper, String, String, FormMethod, Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492714.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The third argument, `FormMethod`, does not take a string, but an enum. Try `FormMethod.Get`.

Comment: @dknaack Ah - I see it. The extra argument +1

Comment: Unfortunately i am over the 200 reputation (upvote) per day limit ;) Thanks anyway. Have a nice day!